# What function form might best fit a set of data involving the Pearson coefficient of a linear set of data?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I've recently developed an interest in statistics, so I decided to write a program which will generate a set of data, storing the Pearson correlation coefficient versus a changing random variance in the data.  Here is the method I wrote to do this:

```
def generateData(nLines, nPoints, gradient, yIntercept, xScaleFactor, randomCoefficientScaleFactor):
    Rs = []
    xValues = []

    for i in range(nLines):
        x = []
        y = []

        for j in range(nPoints):
            x.append(j*xScaleFactor)
            y.append(fLinear(x[j], i*randomCoefficientScaleFactor, gradient, yIntercept))

        dataSet = Data(x, y)

        xValues.append(i*randomCoefficientScaleFactor)
        Rs.append(linearCorrelationCoefficient(dataSet.x, dataSet.y))

    dataSet = Data(xValues, Rs)
    return dataSet
```

And here is the function fLinear():

```
def fLinear(x, randomCoefficient, gradient, yIntercept):
    return gradient*x + yIntercept + randomCoefficient*random.uniform(0,1)
```

I ran this with 200 values for R, 1000 points for each line, and a scale factor on the random value of 75.

Outputting this data to a Desmos graph gives [this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVQf1.jpg)

My first instinct as to which type of function would yield this shape would be a normal distribution, but [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zUhN.jpg), this is not the case. My next thought would be a sigmoid, so I tried three different functions:

- $\frac{1}{e^{kx}+1}$, which [yielded this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dctgj.jpg)
- $erf(kx)$, which [yielded this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYxSS.jpg)
- $tan^{-1}(kx)+1$, which [yielded this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEdbc.jpg)

None of these fit the the data particularly well, so I hoped that someone here knew of any function that better fits this data set.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please explain in words and mathematical formulas what your code is doing?

Comment: My code is doing the following:

-Creating two empty arrays, one for the correlation coefficients, and the other for the values on the x-axis thats associated with (not really a quantity)
-Iterating over the number of lines
-Creating two empty arrays, for the x- and y- coordinates of a series of points.
-Iterating over the number of points
-Generating all of the points for this instance
-Creating a Data object (which is really just composed of 2 arrays) based on these points
-Calculating the correlation coefficient of this data set
-Storing that correlation coefficient and x-value

Comment: It then creates another Data object based on the correlation coefficients and associated x-values, and outputs all of those to the command-line.  f() operates simply as a straight-line equation with a random real number between 0 and the given value randomCoefficient added on.

Comment: That is the general shape of $e^{-x^2}$. But there are infinitely many functions that have this shape, for example $e^{-x^n}$ for $n > 2$ as well. And there are more non-exponentials functions. Probably you can get a good fit with $Ae^{-Bx^2}$, but to find the true form takes analysis, not curve-fitting.